# Concatenar dos columnas y n filas SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenación

Necesito hacer una concatenación de dos columnas con n filas. Se trata de la ruta de un vuelo, esta es la tabla de ejemplo:

| No_tickete | origen | destino | sector_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 273 | XYD | CDG | 1 |
| 273 | CDG | BOG | 2 |
| 273 | BOG | CLO | 3 |
| 273 | CLO | BOG | 4 |
| 273 | BOG | CDG | 5 |
| 273 | CDG | XYD | 6 |
| 274 | XYD | PER | 1 |
| 274 | CLO | BOG | 2 |

Estuve intentandolo con este codigo:

```
SELECT distinct  X.Main_Document_Number
       ,STUFF(( 
             SELECT concat(origen,destino)
                 FROM tabla Y
             WHERE No_tickete = X.No_tickete
             order by sector_no -- este es el orden de las rutas
             FOR XML PATH('')
       ),1,0,'') RUTA
        FROM tabla X
```

Estoy utilizando este codigo, pero me muestra repeticiones entre escalas, ejemplo:

```
XYD-CDG-CDG-BOG-BOG-CLO-CLO-BOG-BOG-CDG-CDG-XYD
```

La salida deberia omitir estos repetidos en los intermedios asi:

```
XYD-CDG-BOG-CLO-BOG-CDG-XYD
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu misma estás concatenando origen y destino, antes de concatenar las distintas filas, dado que el destino de una escala es el origen de la siguiente, allí radica el que se dupliquen los valores.

Lo que tu necesitas, en realidad, es concatenar el primer origen con todos los destinos.

Si el primer origen siempre tiene siempre el `sector_no` igual a `1`, la solución vendría a ser algo como:

```
SELECT   X.Main_Document_Number
       , X.Origen 
         + STUFF(( 
             select concat('-', destino)
               from tabla Y
              where Y.No_tickete = X.No_tickete
              order by Y.sector_no -- este es el orden de las rutas
                for XML Path('')
       ), 1, 0, '') Ruta
  from tabla X
 where X.sector_no = 1
```

Si observas, ahora no haces un `select distinct`, sino que seleccionas solamente aquellas filas que tienen el `sector_no = 1`, con su `Main_Document_Number`, y el `Origen` concatenado con la concatenación de todos los destinos, en orden.

Si las rutas no comienzan siempre con el `sector_no` en `1`, puedes hacer un paso previo para obtener el sector inicial o numerar las filas, en el segundo caso, podría ser, por ejemplo:

```
with
X as (
select *, row_number() over (partition by Main_Document_Number order by sector_no) Contador
  from Tabla
)
```

El campo `contador` siempre iniciará en `1` para cada `Main_Document_Number`, con lo que la lógica anterior queda intacta, solo ajustar el nombre del campo por el que se filtra en la consulta principal.

Comment: Estuve intentando y funiona perfecto para este ejemplo que te dí, el problema es que si la ruta cambia de destino origen, me descarta ese nuevo origen. Ejemplo:

|No_tickete | origen | destino | sector_no
|:--------- |:------:| -------:| -------:|
|274     |   XYD  |  PER    |  1
|274     |   CLO  |  BOG    |  2

Comment: Escribí una respuesta para el problema que planteaste. Considero descortés que, a estas alturas, cambies la pregunta. Si tuviste una omisión, sugiero que escribas una nueva pregunta planteando la nueva situación y dejes esta como estaba, pues con el cambio que estás haciendo la solución es totalmente distinta, como ya has podido comprobar.